# Download file to browser from SFTP server in ASP.NET using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sftp, ssh.net

With SSH.NET, I am trying to trigger a file to be downloaded by the browser instead of directly writing it to the local file storage.

```
using(var saveFile = File.OpenWrite(@"Downloads")) {
  result = client.BeginDownloadFile(remotePath + fileName, saveFile) as SftpUploadAsyncResult;

  client.EndUploadFile(result);
}
```

The above code fails as my the application pool identity doesn't have permission to write files and I cannot give permission as I don't have Admin privileges to my computer.

So better option would be to trigger the download through browser which was working earlier with `FtpWebRequest`.

But my current task is to convert the FTP download to SFTP download.

Can someone suggest the best way to trigger browser download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the file to [`HttpResponse.OutputStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream):

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);

client.DownloadFile(remotePath + fileName, response.OutputStream);
```